# Token questions

Tags: tokens, ether, etherscan

1. When a company has a token that appears on ether-scan, and someone decides to buy the token on ether-scan using eth, will that eth they used to buy the token go to the company? Or does it only just increase the value of the token.
2. Once a person decides to exchange there tokens into eth, will the company have to pay anything for that exchange?

Thank you to anyone who can help me. I am new to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally you cannot buy a token via etherscan. If you are referring to a vanilla ERC20 token, you can only purchase them via an exchange (decentralized or decentralized), peer-to-peer, or through crowdfunding. The eth spent to acquire the token will go to liquidity provider (in case of dencetralized exchanges) or other traders, which could be members of the company that issued the token. Only in the case of crowdfunding the ETH will go directly to the issuing company.